# ASN.1 structure of ECDSA signature in X.509 certificate

Tags: openssl, x509, asn.1, ecdsa

Analyzing a X.509 certificate with ECDSA signature I found a 0x00 byte I can't explain.

The signature of a X.509 certificate should be given in an ASN.1 BIT STRING structure.
For ECDSA the signature consists of two integers (r, s) coded as ASN.1 SEQUENCE of two ASN.1 INTEGERs.

In my example (generated with openssl) I got this:

```
    ASN.1 tag for BIT STRING
     |  length 
     |  |    
     |  |     ASN.1 tag for SEQEUNCE
     |  |     |  length
     |  |     |  |
     |  |     |  |  ASN.1 tag for INTEGER             ASN.1 tag for INTEGER           
     |  |     |  |  |  length                         |  length                       
     |  |     |  |  |  |                              |  |                            
     |  |     |  |  |  |   0x21 bytes integer value   |  |   0x21 bytes integer value 
     |  |     |  |  |  |  ____________|____________   |  |  ____________|____________ 
     v  v     v  v  v  v /                         \  v  v /                         \
... 03 49 00 30 46 02 21 00 D5 F4 76 43 ... A2 BD 95 02 21 00 DF 01 30 24 ... 50 12 32
           ^      
           |
           why is there a 0x00 byte?
```

Why is there an extra 0x00 byte before the ASN.1 SEQUENCE tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First octet of ASN.1 `BIT_STRING` is `Unused Bits` indicator. Bit strings are not always aligned to full octets (1 byte). Since minimum encoded data size is 1 byte, `Unused bits` will store a number of how much bits are not used in encoded value. For example, your data length is exactly 11 bits. To encode 11-bit long string you will use 2 bytes, 16 bits. However, you must indicate that your data length is 11 bits by setting `Unused Bits` octet to 5 (16-11). Possible values for `Unused Bits` octet are 0-7. More details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccertenroll/about-bit-string

Comment: I missed tha fact that the number of unused bits is also coded in a ASN.1 BIT STRING structure. I thought it was up to the user how many bits are actually used. So if the bit string's length is a multiple of 8 bits (i.e. whole bytes) the first byte is always 0. In general its a value in the range of 0..7. Thank you!